# zsh: command not found: mv (I'm trying to move composer.phar)

Tags: laravel, xampp, laravel-8, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to follow a course on Udemy (laravel). I just downloaded XAMPP (I'm on macOS Monterey) and I edited the ~/.zshrc file and added `export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin`

After that I installed composer which worked successfully, but now when I try to run this command: `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` the shell responds with: zsh: `command not found: mv`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you _append_ to your PATH setting in `~/.zshrc` or did you overwrite the path?

Comment: ```~/.zshrc``` was empty. So I guess I appended it

Comment: That seems wrong. Your `~/.zshrc` should not at all be empty.

Comment: It was. I added ```export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin``` to add PHP in the command line and when I enter ```php -v```I get the version of PHP that existed in the XAMPP folder where I wrote the path to in ```~/.zshrc```

Comment: But now commands like mv and composer aren't working. Same error: ```zsh: command not found: composer```or ```zsh: command not found: mv```

Comment: Just writing `export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin` will effectively overwrite your current path and not append to it. The proper approach would be to write `export PATH="$PATH":"/Applications/XAMPP/bin"` to ensure that PATH is prepended to your append.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The file `mv` was not found in your PATH, is your PATH variable setup correctly?
Enter `echo $PATH` to see your PATH variable.

Try `/bin/mv` to see if the binary file exists.

Comment: ```echo $PATH
/Applications/XAMPP/bin```

```/usr/bin/mv
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/bin/mv```

Comment: Have your overwrited your PATH variable? 
Try /bin/mv

Comment: I've put the following line in the ```~/.zshrc``` file: ```export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin```. Also: ```/bin/mv
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory```

Comment: @nobah You overwrited your PATH variable and now it looks for files only in `/Applications/XAMPP/bin` directory, if you want zsh to look for files in `/Applications/XAMPP/bin` as well as the default PATH directories (which is most probably what you want) then add this to your ~/.zshrc file: `path+=('/Applications/XAMPP/bin')`

Comment: it says this: ```export PATH+=/Applications/XAMPP/bin
export: not valid in this context: PATH+```

Comment: @nobah Then try adding this to your ~/.zshrc file:
`export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin :$PATH` and either re-login or do `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I can't access the ~/.zshrc file now ```zsh: command not found: nano``` (sorry for giving you a hard time helping, I really appreciate the help though!) I tried using export PATH in the command line but it keeps saying: ```export: not valid in this context: :/Applications/XAMPP/bin```

Comment: @nobah Also dont forget to remove the line you added previously (`export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin`)

Comment: @nobah You can access the file, but not the command nano as your PATH variable is overwritten. Try using `/bin/nano ~/.zshrc` instead.

Comment: ```/bin/nano ~/.zshrc
zsh: no such file or directory: /bin/nano``` this is what I get now

Comment: Can I edit the file manually using text editor?

Comment: @nobah You can edit the text file as you like. Just make sure to remove the line `export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin` and add `export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin :$PATH` then re-login or enter `source ~/.zshrc` or start a new zsh shell instance.

Comment: I did and I got the nano command working again so I added ```export PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/bin :$PATH``` and saved the ~/.zshrc file. After that the commands stopped working again. Is there a way I can prioritise the default path and then the /applications/XAMPP/bin folder?

Comment: @nobah Do not add a space between `:$PATH` and `.../XAMPP/bin`, also did you run the `source ~/.zshrc` or re-login as I mentioned above?

In that case you want to prepend your own PATH dir to the default PATH variable.
Remove the previous lines you added and add `export  PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/bin`

Comment: I removed the space and it seems to be working now. I can use every command again. Thanks a lot, I kept getting stuck on this!

Answer (score 0):

You messed up your PATH. Do a

```
path+=(/Applications/XAMPP/bin)
```

instead of the `export PATH=...` you are using now. And since you want to fiddle with the PATH in your .zshrc, I also suggest to do a

```
typeset -aU path
```

near the top of your .zshrc to avoid duplicate PATH entries when you launch an interactive subshell.